# Resampling of mouse events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events for some interactions in my applications. The issue is that 'mouse move' events are sampled discretely and this results into some elements being "skipped" if the mouse is moved too fast across them.

My question: Is there an elegant way of resampling the mouse move events in javascript/jQuery? ie. if I detect that the distance between two `mousemove`events is too large could I simulate one, say, halfway in between? The complication here is that I do not just want `mousemove` events to trigger, but also `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Comment: Never hard that one would ever need some sort of double precision on mousemove, just hitting the wall... may you share with us why you need this? I'm almost sure there's another way.

Comment: Effectively what I am trying to do is connecting a number of boxes by "chaining" them up. i.e. I'm listening for `mouseenter` events, which adds each element to the chain. However, as mentioned, if the mouse moves too fast across an element that handler is never triggered. This is compounded by the fact that the user can zoom out, in which case each box gets smaller and thus is more likely to get skipped. Does that make sense? I'm also open to alternative solutions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how the border would make `mouseenter` faster? I agree that this is not ideal and I'm not even sure it's feasible, but is there an alternative approach?

Comment: have you tried to capture the mouse at the parent element, the MOVE event, and check if it has more resolution? Maybe you can use only that event and decide which box belogs... that should be faster maybe?

Comment: @rupps an invisible border might overlap other borders and in any case make the result inaccurate, cause you might be over a border, but now want to rarget a desired element.....

Comment: I've tried to interpolate. i.e. "draw" a line between two consecutive `mousemove` events of the parents and then check for intersections with the children. But since I can have a large number of children I cannot do that at the speed I would need to. That's why I was thinking it would be better if I could let the browser handle that for me.

Comment: @chopper on a 50px width element there's a 50% chance you might not trigger an mouseenter event over that element... Bout really you need to maniacally move your mouse.....

Comment: @chopper could you post some screenshots to see what we're talking about?

Comment: @chopper I've done recently an UI elements selector that basically does: [click + drag] and all elements that are inside the start + end area become selected. The trick was to (actually on mousemoveend timeout to leverage browser calculations) get all the elements that intersect the rectangular area. So even if you're Sonic with your mouse... not one element was unselected. 100% accuracy guaranteed.

Comment: Yeah that's an option, but the order in which the elements are connected matter to me, too, as well as the z-order. The browser handles all of that nicely for me, but not at the speed I would need to. Also I want to show the chaining while it is in progress, i.e. before the `mouseup`. I had hoped there was an elegant way around this..

Comment: @chopper I'm afraid no. If yes... it's some code out of this world. Cause the browser generates the mousemove event *precision* (I think it follows every browser requestframe interval) The trick might be to alert a user if it goes crazy with it's mouse. Really, if you build a object oriented way to listen to elements and their mouseenter events, pushing inmemory all those info into an array... you'll get pretty good results...

Comment: I tried, but calculating bounding boxes for a large number of elements, then calculating intersections with the line between the last two `mousemove` events and then checking for order of intersection taking into account z-index is unfortunately too much to do `live`, i.e. on every `mousemove`. I guess I can do it on `mouseup`, but it does involve me replicating a lot of functionality that the browser already has